# Windows RT : Reading text file from project folder

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

I'm creating a windows rt application which contains more than 1000 .txt files from which I'm getting their contents.

These text files are part of my project but I can't read them with code.

This is my code

```
    static async Task ReadFile(string filePath, List<string> list)
    {
        try
        {
            StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///" + filePath));
            var readThis = await FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(file);
            foreach (var line in readThis)
            {
                list.Add(line);
            }

        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {
        }
    }
```

where filePath is : "txt/data/14b.txt.

When code is executed Lists are filled with the data but application crashes and I'm sent in this line of app.g.i.cs

```
            if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
```

any ideas ?

Comment: Look at the contents of the `e` variable in the debugger, it gives the context of the exception that was thrown. What does it say?

Comment: [System.ArgumentException] = {"Value does not fall within the expected range."}

Comment: What is the line that throws? Are you sure it's located in that code? Put a breakpoint there and see what happens.

Comment: http://i50.tinypic.com/2w4bf4z.png

Comment: Well, of course. What's interesting is to know what line in your code throws the exception. What you see here is the default `catch` for the thrown exception. So put breakpoints in your code where you think the exception is not thrown yet, and step through until you find the faulty line. Then figure out what's happening from that point.

Comment: What is the complete stack trace for the System.ArgumentException?

Comment: @Mic I can't find what's causing the exception this is my code http://pastebin.com/Y0ez7sX6

Comment: I found what was causing the error, my method was declared with the void keyword, I've changed it to Task and things worked!

Comment: ok then. You should remove your question then, it will not be of interest for future visitors :)

Answer (score 2):

Try marking your text files Build Action as Content. Then

```
var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync( new Uri( "ms-appx:///" + filePath ) );
```

Should load a file.

Answer (score 1):

```
var storageFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri(String.Format("ms-appx:///{Project name}/txt/data/{0}", fileName)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with replacing

```
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///" + filePath));
```

to

```
var ProjectFolder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
StorageFile file = await ProjectFolder.GetFileAsync(fileName);
```